# Return different result for Ok and BadRequest in Rest API in .net6.0

Tags: c#, rest, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

After upgrade from .NET Framwork 4.8 I can not return different result for Ok and BadRequest and the Swagger document has also changed to reflect it.

In this case I return nothing for Ok and my error object for BadRequest

```
 [ProducesResponseType(200)]
 [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Models.Response), 400)]
 [HttpGet("/api/Order/ValidateMSISDN/{msisdn}")]
 public IActionResult ValidateMSISDN(string msisdn)
```

Return part looks like this:

```
resp = new Models.Response("211", "Msisdn not valid", "Telefonnumret stämmer inte");
return BadRequest(resp);
```

or

```
return Ok();
```

If everything is OK.

In Program.cs i have the following:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

New Swagger looks like this:
[image: New Swagger]

Old Swagger:
[image]

What do I need to do to make this work again?

Comment: Are you sure not using `[ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(StatusCodes.Status200OK,Type = typeof(Models.Response))]` ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: can you give it a try with     [SwaggerResponse(200, Type = typeof(your enttity object))]
?

Comment: I have tried that also, but no difference. Same problem